# How to install PyGSL? (Windows 7, 64 bit, Python 2.7, GSL 1.15)

Tags: gcc, windows-7, python-2.7, gsl, pygsl

I'm trying to install PyGSL on my computer (64 bit Windows 7), with Python 2.7 and GSL 1.15 installed. I'm pretty much stuck and I would love for some extra help. GSL installed fine, but its the wrapper that's the problem. For some reason I can't build pygsl. Apparently gcc is the problem (got the same problem on another windows machine). Or it could be that pygsl appears to be using a file named AMD64 while my computer is x86. I would love to use the windows binary for pygsl, but it only exists for python 2.5, and my project needs 2.6 or higher. I've used both the windows binary for GSL and built it from source, but I get the same problem either way. I tried copying dlls from GSL into pygsl but that didn't work. Some forums mentioned a file called gsl.dll but I can't seem to find it. I've also tried to use Cygwin and to compile with minGW32 to no avail.

cmds I ran:

```
python setup.py install
python setup.py build
python setup.py build_ext -i
python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32
```

Any ideas?? Thanks.

Cheers,
Bereket

Got the same message in Cygwin as in the windows cmd prompt. Error message:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe setup.py build_ext -i
numpy
Forcing DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
Building testing ufuncs!
running build_ext
building 'errno' extension
C compiler: gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -mno-cygwin -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes

compile options: '-DSWIG_COBJECT_TYPES=1 -DGSL_RANGE_CHECK=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DNUMERIC=0 -DPYGSL_GSL_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPYGSL_GSL_MINOR_VERSION=15 -UNDEBUG -IC:\Users\Bereket\gsl-1.15\include -IInclude -I. -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c'
gcc -g -DDEBUG -DMS_WIN64 -mno-cygwin -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DSWIG_COBJECT_TYPES=1 -DGSL_RANGE_CHECK=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DNUMERIC=0 -DPYGSL_GSL_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPYGSL_GSL_MINOR_VERSION=15 -UNDEBUG -IC:\Users\Bereket\gsl-1.15\include -IInclude -I. -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c src/init/errorno.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\init\errorno.o
Found executable C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe
gcc -g -mno-cygwin -shared build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\init\errorno.o -LC:\Users\Bereket\gsl-1.15\lib -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o C:\Python27\Lib\pygsl-0.9.5\pygsl\errno.pyd
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\init\errorno.o: In function `add_errno':
/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/pygsl-0.9.5/src/init/errorno.c:14: undefined reference to `__imp__PyInt_FromLong'
/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/pygsl-0.9.5/src/init/errorno.c:20: undefined reference to `__imp__PyDict_SetItemString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\init\errorno.o: In function `initerrno':
/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/pygsl-0.9.5/src/init/errorno.c:37: undefined reference to `__imp__Py_InitModule4_64'
/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/pygsl-0.9.5/src/init/errorno.c:40: undefined reference to `__imp__PyModule_GetDict'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: Command "gcc -g -mno-cygwin -shared build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\init\errorno.o -LC:\Users\Bereket\gsl-1.15\lib -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o C:\Python27\Lib\pygsl-0.9.5\pygsl\errno.pyd" failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure now that my GSL install with Cygwin failed / had unresolved dependencies. I'm now trying to install it with visual studio 2010. Here are some good sites for doing that:

[Instructions](http://4fire.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/gsl-1-15-building-with-visual-studio-2010/)

[Alt Method](https://code.google.com/p/gsl-w32/)

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Python 2.7 compiler for Windows is a good place to start
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` does the trick for me. 
If this doesn't work let me know. You might need to add an environment variable.

Is your Python 32 or 64? To check open Python and do

```
import sys
sys.versions
```